# Space between line-comment character(s) and start of actual comment

Tags: coding-style, comments

I realize that this rule might differ from one company's coding standards to another, but in general, which is preferred?

1. With a space after the line-comment:

   ```
   int foo = Bar(quux + 1); // compensate for quux being off by 1

   foo = Bar(quux + 1) # compensate for quux being off by 1
   ```
2. No space after the line comment:

   ```
   int foo = Bar(quux + 1); //compensate for quux being off by 1

   foo = Bar(quux + 1) #compensate for quux being off by 1
   ```

I haven't been able to find *anything* online regarding this aspect of coding style. My guess is that including a space is the preferred style for all languages, but I'd like some "hard evidence" to confirm or deny this.

---

It sounds so far like everyone has **anecdotal** evidence that using a space is preferred.  Can anyone point me in the direction of some official or otherwise published **coding standards** that directly address the issue of comment formatting and whether a space should be used?

Comment: I don't know why this should be that much important. What IS important, is what actually works for you and for your environment. Not, what someone has defined - and this is actually what the famous *C++ Coding Standards* says (more or less).

Comment: I would suggest that any coding standard that DID specify this, similar to The One True Brace Style, should be tossed in the bin. Or left behind when you quit and move to a sensible company.

Comment: @AviD, I disagree: nailing down useless "degrees of freedom" in formatting is a key aspect of coding standards -- you appear to define "a sensible company" as one that doesn't care for "egoless programming" and "shared code ownership", while for me it's crucial to emphasize those aspects. A large codebase that's maddeningly inconsistent in trivial aspects is that much harder to maintain and reuse, and a lot of time is wasted in "bikeshed" debates on trivial issues of style -- nail them down once and for all, and, full speed ahead.

Comment: One way to completely destroy programmer morale is to try to remove every degree of freedom that they have with pointless and dictatorial rules. Surely code reviews would be better spent reviewing the quality of code, not the placement of spaces describing that code?

Comment: @aabs, I emphatically do NOT see "programmer morale" being "completely destroyed" at Google, my current employer: on the contrary, I've never seen developers happier or more empowered. A year ago I made a lateral step from the management ladder to the developer ladder and I'm even happier now than I was when I was managing.  Part of this empowerment are **rigid**, **strictly enforced** style guides established and evolved by developers' consensus for all the major languages we use (C++, Java, Python, ...) -- removing useless degrees of freedom (and unending fights over them) is VERY useful!

Comment: @aabs, cont.: I've done many presentations on code reviews making (among others) the same point -- don't waste reviewer brainpower on idiotic issues such as spacing (and brace placement in other languages than Python;-): have those rules rigidly, inflexibly enforced by automated tools that stop any code from polluting the shared-ownership codebase if it breaks the rigid style guidelines. **This** is what empowers reviewers to focus on what really matters without being distracted by idiosyncratic likes and dislikes for irrelevant lexical issues (and future maintainers, etc, etc).

Comment: @aabs, fin.: if you don't understand how constraints empower and unchain a person's _real_ creativity, I suspect you've never written a haiku, a sonnet, or even a limerick.  I have.  (In fact, in my teens, before I discovered the even-richer constraints-induced creative flowering of software development with strict style rules, I won prizes in national poetry competitions;-).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Python's official style guide, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), is very clear about this issue:

> Each line of a block
>       comment starts with a # and a single space (unless it is indented
>   text
>       inside the comment).

and:

> Inline
>       comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement.
>       They should start with a # and a single space.

This confirms everybody's anecdotal evidence, but I think this is the first answer to quote "some official or otherwise published coding standards" as requested;-).

Comment: In SwiftLint 0.42.0 a new `comment_spacing` rule is added. It says 

> Comment Spacing Violation: Prefer at least one space after slashes for comments.

Answer (score 57):

I've developed software in many languages for about 10 years on projects large and small. I have yet to see anyone intentionally not use a space. In the scheme of things it doesn't really matter that much (after all, we all know those are comments and can read them), but I do think the no-space version looks similar to commented-out code and requires an extra millisecond of brain power to confirm it is a comment :-)

Comment: It tends to be that you have an extra non-space character after the marker symbol to indicate special treatment of the comment.  Doxygen with /**  for example; I've seen variants with @ and other ones.

Comment: As someone who has literally never once used a space between the slashes and actual comment, this has never occurred to me. I don't have any issues differentiating between a comment and commented out code, but maybe that's just because I'm used to it? Idunno. Jonathan Leffler makes a good point about certain comment parsing software using it, though.

Answer (score 35):

In the last 24 years, I've developed and maintained code professionally in C, C++, Pascal, BASIC, Java, Perl, Objective C, Bourne shell, bash, csh, tcsh, and assembly for 68K, PowerPC and x86. During this time, I've noticed a few things...

1. Comments with leading spaces are at least 1000 times more common than comments without spaces. Missing leading spaces in comments are most often typos due to hasty typing.
2. I can't remember ever seeing comments in sample code in a professional book or manual without the space.
3. The only professional developers I've known who routinely omit the leading space in comments grew up using a non-Western, ideographic writing system that doesn't use spaces.
4. I have never, ever seen an official company coding style that tells people to omit the leading space in comments.

So all in all, I would say the overwhelming evidence is that a space after the line-comment is preferred.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't noticed the connection between being a native Chinese-reader and comment (and code) formatting, but it rings true.

Answer (score 7):

I just came across [StyleCop's SA1005 rule](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1005.htm), which states:

> A violation of this rule occurs when a
>   single-line comment does not begin
>   with a single space. For example:
>
> ```
> private void Method1()
> {
>   //A single-line comment.
>   //   A single-line comment.
> }
> ```
>
> The comments should begin with a single space after the leading forward slashes:
>
> ```
> private void Method1()
> {
>   // A single-line comment.
>   // A single-line comment.
> }
> ```

Since StyleCop is in one way or another a Microsoft product, I'd say this qualifies as an official coding standard with respect to spaces in line-comments.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly avoid having comments on the end of a line of code, because then the comments hang off the end and aren't as easy to parse when scanning. When I have a good reason, though, I like to use **two** spaces to separate code and comments (then one space after the comment marker). It just makes it easier for the eye...

Consider:

```
    int top;  // Index of the top of the stack.
```

versus:

```
    int top; // Index of the top of the stack.
```

Subjectively, it seems like two spaces just makes it easier to split up what's code and what's not.

Comment: The question is more about what goes after the // than what goes before - to be spaced out, or not to be spaced out?

Comment: It took me four re-reads to finally see what the difference was between your two samples.  Guess it's not that important a difference to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found the standard (according to Wikipedia) for commenting in Java. This is supposed to be "consistent with the Sun Microsystems Javadoc standards":

> ```
> /**
>  * Registers the text to display in a tool tip.   The text
>  * displays when the cursor lingers over the component.
>  * @param text  the string to display.  If the text is null, 
>  *              the tool tip is turned off for this component.
>  */
> ```

So I'm starting to think the standard is a space.
Also, all the other examples have a space.

Answer (score 0):

The Google C++ Styleguide requires two spaces https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/cpplint/cpplint.py#L3014
i.e. `int foo = 1337 //  bar`

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Java Style Guide **Formatting** section](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.6.2-horizontal-whitespace) requires putting a space on both sides of a comment:

> **4.6.2 Horizontal whitespace**
>
> Beyond where required by the language or other style rules, and apart from literals, comments and Javadoc, a single ASCII space also appears in the following places only.
>
> ...
>
> 6. On both sides of the double slash (`//`) that begins an end-of-line comment. Here, multiple spaces are allowed, but not required.